# What is this syntax: {variable1, variable2, variable3}?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I saw the following ES6 code and was confused:

```
class GuitarAmp {
  constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      cabinet, distortion, volume
    });
  }
}
```

What is the second parameter to Object.assign? It's not an object, so what is it? I just noticed it's part of the constructor arguments too, this part:

```
{ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}
```

I'm unfamiliar with this new syntax so I don't know how to look it up, since I don't know what it's called. Anyone know the term?

Comment: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: search for "Shorthand property names (ES2015)" in the above link - basically it's equal to `Object.assign(this, {
      cabinet: cabinet, distortion: distortion, volume: volume
});`

Comment: @Aerovistae It's not three parameters, it's one parameter object that is destructured.

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/object-assign.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the above code, I believe:

```
{
  cabinet, distortion, volume
}
```

is in ES5:

```
{
   cabinet: cabinet,
   distortion: distortion,
   volume: volume,
}
```

It's just a short form of writing the object, when the **key and value are same.**

Comment: Fun fact: this also works for functions. `function myFunction() {}`.
`var obj = { myFunction }`. or: `var obj = { myFunction() {} }`.

Comment: May I note for future readers that this syntax only works with previously declared variables, and does not allow literals.`var d = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` will error. Makes sense. It's just a shorthand for grouping some variables into an object.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of first param is `{}` but if it is provided, we have nested default values in first param object like `cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0'`

Hence, if first object param is provided with e.g. `{ cabinet = 'test', distortion = '4', volume = '2' }` then, `this` would be as follows

```
{ 
  cabinet: 'test', 
  distortion: '4', 
  volume: '2' 
}
```

otherwise, it will have the default values provided in param.

Answer (score 1):

It is an object literal using the shorthand syntax. It is just syntactic sugar.

```
var a = "A";
var b = "B";
var c = "C";
```

These two are the same:

```
{ a: a, b: b, c: c }
{ a, b, c }
```

In other words, if you throw a variable into the object literal then the property name will become that of the variable name.